# How to get this link to work on this element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I was wondering how to get the link/a href to work on the text inside the box? I'm not sure what is causing the link to not work/function. I'd like to keep the animation if possible, not sure if this is what is causing the link to not work. Thank you for your help in advance!

Here is my html and css:

```css
.sign a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
s
.sign a:hover {
    color:aqua;
}

.sign {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: -10;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  /* sign width */
  width: 150px;
  /* Give it a white border */
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  /* pad content text away from the edges of the sign */
  padding: 1em 1em .75em;
  /* give it a drop shadow and inset shadow at the top */
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* setup a default background red and a red gradient where supported */
  background-color: #a1cdad;
  //background: linear-gradient(top, #ff9696 0%, #c80000 100%);
  /* attempt to get rid of jaggies when rotated */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* nice rounded corners */
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* set the swing origin (nail body) */
  transform-origin: 50% -65px;
  /* animate the swing with pendulum-style easing */
  animation: swing 1.5s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.sign:hover {
  /* Hover over the sign to stop the animation */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.sign p {
  /* Typography */
  /* let's have uppercase.. */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* bold... */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* white... */
  color: #fff;
  /* centered text */
  text-align: center;
/*  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: normal;
}

.one P {
  font-size:1.5em;
  line-height:1.5em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.sign IMG {
  display:block;
  width:3.5em;
  margin:auto;
}

.sign:before {
  /* string */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* string thickness/color */
  border: 2px dotted #444;
  /* hide string after connection with sign */
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  /* string 'size' (as a -45deg rotated square) */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* string position */
  top: -55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  /* string construct */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* string curved round nail body (unseen) */
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.sign:after {
  /* nail */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* nail head size */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /* nail head as a circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* nail position */
  top: -75px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  /* nail head default color + gradient (where supported) */
  background: #4c4c4c;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #666666 25%, #474747 39%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
}
/* sign swinging animation sequence */
@keyframes swing {
  0% { transform: rotate(-3deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(3deg) }
}
```

```html
 <div class="sign one">
     <a href="#"><p>start my<br>order</p></a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is `z-index: -10` on `.sign` which moves all the thing to background. And lack of `z-index` on `a` which makes it hidden behind absolutely positioned elements.

See the updated snippet:

```css
.sign a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative; z-index:1;
}

.sign a:hover {
    color:aqua;
}

.sign {
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* z-index: -10; */
    margin-top: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
  /* sign width */
  width: 150px;
  /* Give it a white border */
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  /* pad content text away from the edges of the sign */
  padding: 1em 1em .75em;
  /* give it a drop shadow and inset shadow at the top */
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* setup a default background red and a red gradient where supported */
  background-color: #a1cdad;
  //background: linear-gradient(top, #ff9696 0%, #c80000 100%);
  /* attempt to get rid of jaggies when rotated */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* nice rounded corners */
  border-radius: 15px;
  /* set the swing origin (nail body) */
  transform-origin: 50% -65px;
  /* animate the swing with pendulum-style easing */
  animation: swing 1.5s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.sign:hover {
  /* Hover over the sign to stop the animation */
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.sign p {
  /* Typography */
  /* let's have uppercase.. */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* bold... */
  font-weight: bold;
  /* white... */
  color: #fff;
  /* centered text */
  text-align: center;
/*  text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);*/
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: normal;
}

.one P {
  font-size:1.5em;
  line-height:1.5em;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}


.sign IMG {
  display:block;
  width:3.5em;
  margin:auto;
}

.sign:before {
  /* string */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* string thickness/color */
  border: 2px dotted #444;
  /* hide string after connection with sign */
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  /* string 'size' (as a -45deg rotated square) */
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* string position */
  top: -55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  /* string construct */
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  /* string curved round nail body (unseen) */
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.sign:after {
  /* nail */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  /* nail head size */
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  /* nail head as a circle */
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* nail position */
  top: -75px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -4px;
  /* nail head default color + gradient (where supported) */
  background: #4c4c4c;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #4c4c4c 0%, #595959 12%, #666666 25%, #474747 39%, #2c2c2c 50%, #000000 51%, #111111 60%, #2b2b2b 76%, #1c1c1c 91%, #131313 100%);
}
/* sign swinging animation sequence */
@keyframes swing {
  0% { transform: rotate(-3deg) }
  100% { transform: rotate(3deg) }
}
```

```html
<div class="sign one">
     <a href="#"><p>start my<br>order</p></a>
 </div>
```